# How to use Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API with a new GA4 account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API with a GA4 account, but since there is no viewid parameter in GA4 I cant call the API.
I have tried to use propertid instead of viewid but I come up to a insufficientPermissions 403 error.
I also cant find any documentation about the migration of MCF API to the new GA4.

The call i am making is to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?access_token=TOKEN&ids=ga:189118519&start-date=2020-11-23&end-date=2020-11-29&metrics=mcf%3AtotalConversions%2Cmcf%3AtotalConversionValue&dimensions=mcf%3AsourcePath&filters=mcf%3AconversionGoalNumber%3D%3D001&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000
```

Comment: Can i have the link to the MCF API for GA4 that you are using?

Comment: Yes, the url is the following :   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMDxsHFLt9ttufR9ERmm81RS_5aRxFK9kv7Yb4nzUBvO3xQnSV2N7o8XgOA7RA20Pl4M5VApgxeaaF4LlriyxVXN2lLVti6b7lHARoeROVUiZFLa1V3UZROWMdgLCwNyYuH_hGCqL1O5DXpDnoXadoAZc5s&ids=ga:189118519&start-date=2020-11-23&end-date=2020-11-29&metrics=mcf%3AtotalConversions%2Cmcf%3AtotalConversionValue&dimensions=mcf%3AsourcePath&filters=mcf%3AconversionGoalNumber%3D%3D001&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000

Comment: Thats an api for Universal analytics it wont work with GA4 check my anwser.

Comment: @ThanasisPapailiou Were you able to find the equivalent call to mcf in GA4 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that universal analytics and GA4 are completely different systems. They can not be compared, and an api that worked on universal analytics does not support GA4

The call you are making is to the [Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3) Works with universal analytics.

To my knowledge there is no equivalate yet that works with GA4 accounts

For GA4 we currently have two bata APIs, which are subject to change often.

- [Data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) equivalent to the reporting api v4 for universal analytics.
- [Admin api GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_summaries) equivalent to the management api for universal analytics

To my knowledge there is no MCF api for GA4